# New exit node with new identity that hasn't already been used?

Tags: anonymity, identity-change

I am using Tor to vote on a poll that tracks the IP address of the voter. Upon clicking new identity sometimes I get a previous used exit node instead of a new one. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I am only trying to do it for 3 days. I know there are some similar questions already asked, but they were unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refer to this Q&A to get some information about your question: [How can I get a different exit node IP each time I get a new identity?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6234/how-can-i-get-a-different-exit-node-ip-each-time-i-get-a-new-identity)

In general, the easiest way, is to record your exit node, then once you are done with it, request a the new identity, check the new exit node of new identity, and if it is same as one of your previous exit node, request a new identity again until the exit node is different than all your previous exit nodes. Another way is mentioned in the reference Q&A mentioned above, but it is tedious and cumbersome. I personally will not implement that method.

To check the exit node, once you started the Tor browser you will see 'about:tor' page which says:
 **Congratulations!**

**This browser is configured to use Tor.**

**You are now free to browse the Internet anonymously.**

**Test Tor Network Settings**

Click The test Tor Network Setting

Then you get to this page:  https://check.torproject.org/?lang=en_US

On this page you can see your IP address.  This is your exit IP address.  Record it on a paper for your future reference. Then proceed to do what you want to do. If it does not take more than 10 minutes, you probably stay with this exit node. Once you are done with your business and you are ready to request a new identity. Click the new identity bottom and do the same thing as I mentioned before. Again record your IP address which is your exit IP address as before on the paper and make sure it is not same as last time. If it is same as last time, again request a new identity and check the IP address again. You have to do this each time you request a new identity and keep writing the IP addresses. After a while you would have a list of IP addresses which you need to check the IP address of your new identity against this enlarging list.

Some words of caution:

1. The exit node might be from anywhere on the Globe. If you are interested in special geographical location and want your exit IP address to be from that general geographical location, look at these Q&As for more information:

[What's the correct syntax for listing multiple ExitNodes?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/5977/whats-the-correct-syntax-for-listing-multiple-exitnodes/5978#5978)

[Can I exit from a specific country or node?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node)

2. Tor network may use several exit IP address concurrently. This may or may not interfer with what you want to do. Look at these Q&As for more information:

[When I use Tor, occasionally I get two different IP address simultaneously](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/when-i-use-tor-occasionally-i-get-two-different-ip-address-simultaneously)

[Is it possible to know which entry node, middle node, and exit node one is using while using TBB?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/is-it-possible-to-know-which-entry-node-middle-node-and-exit-node-one-is-using)

Comment: How do you check the new exit node of the new identity?  So there is no simple config to use only new nodes that haven't already been used recently?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer Dear, The answer is amended to further answer your question and comment.